# Inno Setup: Ignore SSL Certificate errors using the third party tool DwinsHs

Tags: ssl, inno-setup, dwinshs

I use a third party tool by the name of [DwinsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php) for Inno Setup.

This third party tool provides me the capability for downloading files as part of the installation.

I want to send an HTTPS request using the function `DwinsHs_ReadRemoteURL`.
I want the request to ignore all TLS (SSL) certificate errors but I can't find a way.

This third party tool is Open Source and this function is defined in `dwinshs.iss`, which you get by downloading the third party tool.

How can I ignore all SSL certificate errors in an HTTPS request using `DwinsHs_ReadRemoteURL` in the third party tool [DwinsHs](http://www.han-soft.com/dwinshs.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dwinshs.iss` uses the WinInet API. With this API, to ignore the unknown CA error, you have to call the [`InternetSetOption` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptionw).

That's somewhat complicated as it takes a pointer to integer with the security flags as its argument. Inno Setup does not support pointers to integers. But it supports [pointers to structures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6545658/850848) (as you have commented). So you can wrap the integer to a structure.

You need to declare an alternative name for the `InternetSetOption` that takes the structure instead of the string (again as the Inno Setup does not support generic pointers, otherwise single declaration would suffice).

```pascal
const
  INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS = 31;
  SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA = $00000100;

type
  TInteger = record
    Value: Integer;
  end;

function InternetSetOptionInt(
  hInet: HINTERNET; dwOption: DWORD; var lpBuffer: TInteger; dwBufferLength: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'InternetSetOptionA@wininet.dll stdcall delayload setuponly';
```

And use it like:

```pascal
SecurityFlags.Value := SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
InternetSetOptionInt(
  hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, SecurityFlags, SizeOf(SecurityFlags))
```

(after the `hRequest` is assigned in `dwinshs.iss`).

---

Or use a plain HTTP instead. HTTPS set to ignore certificate errors is not secure anyway.

---

Or use a different library to download the files.

The [Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/) can ignore all certificate errors with:

```pascal
idpSetOption('InvalidCert', 'ignore');
```

Comment: Invalid number of parameters in the function `InternetSetOption`

Comment: I also tried just using using a plain HTTP request but it fails with error code 6, but when I use a website with a valid certificate it executes successfully. Could it be that HTTP requests check a certificate somehow?

Comment: And I have clients that block HTTP but not HTTPS to make my situation worse.

Comment: Im having problems using the Inno Download Plugin in my code. I use `DwinsHs_ReadRemoteURL` `OnRead` fallback to update my progress bar. I don't see any options in this plugin to update my own progress bar.

Comment: I will open a new question for this

Comment: I see the use of `InternetSetOption` in `dwinshs.iss`. If they use `InternetSetOption` then why can't I?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12601867/1538099, this post shows how to use pointers for external dlls

Comment: Still doesn't work, what did u mean by `SizeOf(SecurityFlagsSize)`? I just used `SizeOf(SecurityFlags)`. Maybe that's why it still doesn't work?

Comment: I still can't download with an invalid certificate

Comment: It's a self signed certificate on my localhost

Comment: `InternetSetOptionInt ` returns false

Comment: `DLLGetLastError ` returns 0, I do `InternetSetOptionInt` after `Result := CONNECT_ERROR_OPENSESSION;` just like u recommended.

Comment: Now `InternetSetOptionInt ` returns true but the download still doesn't work when I do an HTTPS request

Comment: It works once I changed `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA = $00000100;` to `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA = $00003300;`

Comment: Good! + You better define `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID = $00001000` `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID = $00002000` etc